# How to set filter tcpdump by tcp.len

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump

How can I set a filter with `tcpdump` to filter `tcp.len !=0`

in Wireshark . it's easy, but how can I set that filter  in `tcpdump` ?

Answer (score 1):

Not easy but i found it from the *man* page of tcpdump

```
 tcpdump -ni eth0  tcp and ' (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) >0  )'
```

`ip[2:2]`  is the *Total Length* of the IP packet

`((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)`  is *Internet Header Length* size of IP header

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Packet_structure

`tcp[12]&0xf0`   is the *Data offset* of the TCP Segment Header

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure